# can we connect iPad2 and iTouch using Gamekit?

Tags: ios, ipad, gamekit, gksession

I have this doubt, can we connect iPad2 and iTouch using Gamekit ? I tried Apples GKTank example along with several others available tutorials regarding the same. But I did not have successful connection between them. Anyone knows why this happened ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can.  There should be no difference between connecting an iPad to an iPod or an iPhone to an iPhone.  Are you making sure that both devices have bluetooth turned on or both are on the same wi-fi network?

Comment: ya. iPad can detect iTouch but when I say coonect iTouch does not show up accept connection alertview. iPad is running 4.3.5 and iTouch 4.2.1 is that causing it ?